# Node env variables not working on IDE or PM2

Tags: node.js

Node js server is not taking the env variables when I run it on `ide` or if I use `pm2` to run it.
I have the following files

```
  -client
  -server
     -package.json
     -server.js
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const https = require("https");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.WEB_PORT || 3001;

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);

let server;
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){
    server = https.createServer(app);
}else{
    server = http.createServer(app);
}

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`App running on: http://localhost:${port}`));
```

I am setting the NODE_ENV as follows:

**Working using node cmd**

```
 export NODE_ENV=production
 node server/server.js
```

This prints `production` and server starts in production mode.

**Not working using pm2 or on ide**

```
export NODE_ENV=production
pm2 start server/server.js
```

This prints `undefined` and it doesn't start server in production. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you try to set a config file and pass the env variable as parameter? e.g `pm2 start server/some_config.js --env production` . More info on how to use `pm` configs here: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/